# i have a submit button that i want to redirect to another router link when i click on submit button

Tags: reactjs

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <form action="ValidateMobileNumber.js">     
   <button class="button" type="submit"> Submit</button> 
   </form>
   </div>
```

I have tried this code, but its not redirecting

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can do it using `history.push("/url")`. Which version of React Router do you use and is this function in a component which is rendered by a `Router`?

Comment: Before asking a question here, probably you need to learn, Javascript, then react first. And specific to this question you should take look at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components  for working with forms in React then the router libabry you are using, e.g. react-router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>     
   <button class="button" type="submit"> Submit</button> 
   </form>
</div>
```

function

```
handleSubmit=e=>{
 this.props.history.push('/');
}
```